# Post запрос покороче

Tags: .net, http

Как сделать POST запрос с минимумом писанины? Интересует `urlencoded` и `multipart`. Вроде такого:

```
http.PostAsync("http://ya.ru", new PostData() {
    {"1", "2"},
    {"3", "4"},

});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
new WebClient().UploadValues("http://ya.ru", new NameValueCollection()
{
    {"1", "2"},
    {"3", "4"}
});
```

Comment: WebClient это не System.Net.Http.HttpClient? Вопрос снесли, а какой из них лучше? И можно ли то же самое для HttpClient?

Comment: @SmitJohnth `HttpClient` - это базовый класс для клиентов rest-сервисов. Он умеет сам сериализовать данные (в какой-то мере). WebClient - это просто хелпер для отправки стандартных видов запросов, но никакой строгой типизации или сериализации от него лучше не ждать. Все зависит от того, какие и куда вы собираетесь слать запросы. Вопрос был про "меньше писанины", так что наверное лучше `WebClient`.

Comment: Создал вопрос, можешь там объяснить? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438753/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-httpclient-%D0%B8-webclient

Comment: @SmitJohnth я вроде как уже объяснил :) у классов разное назначение. Может быть кто-то еще ответит.

Comment: Ну назначение одинаковое - делать http запросы :)